# Spinner will not populate and won't set arrayadapter

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner, android-arrayadapter

My app redirects from home screen to city screen through the tap of a button. After I go the city screen. I'm trying to populate a spinner(id = countries). But, when I run it eclipse it opens up an empty spinner in my city class.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_city);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city, container, false);

    String[] test = {"test1", "test2"};
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.countries);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
    adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adapt);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: spinner likely belong to `framgent_city.xml`

Comment: yea. my spinner is in framgent_city.xml

Comment: so, I replace my onCreate() with onCreateView()??

Comment: no you are supposed to initialzie spinner in fragmet's onCreateView. Follow the link at the top of your post

Comment: I did do that and it fixes the problem to an extent. but now the spinner will not populate. i uploaded the edited code

Comment: use `ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891785/spinner-wont-populate-from-my-array/23894164#23894164. possible duplicate